# ASP MVC FileStreamResult OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, asp.net, memorystream, chunking, filestreamresult

I have a large zip file (500MB or greater) that I am reading into a MemoryStream and return as a FileStreamResult.  However, I am getting a OutOfMemory Exception for files over 200MB.  Within my Action I have the following code:

```
MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
using (var fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
   //Response.BufferOutput = false;   // to prevent buffering
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
   int bytesRead = 0;
   while ((bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
   {
      outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
   }
}

outputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
return new FileStreamResult(outputStream, content_type);
```

Comment: I do not want to use ReadAllBytes because of 2GB limit and also because of the memory issues when reading entire file into memory at once.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the solution proposed on this page:

[OutOfMemoryException when sending a big file 500mb using filestream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362849/outofmemoryexception-when-send-big-file-500mb-using-filestream-aspnet)

It shows how to read the file into an `IStream` and send the Response.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer.  Link worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the file into a MemoryStream you still need to allocate the memory for the whole file, as internally the MemoryStream is nothing else than a byte array.

So currently you are reading your file into a large memory buffer using a smaller intermediate (also in memory) buffer.

Why not forward the file stream directly to the FileStreamResult?

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    return new FileStreamResult(fs, content_type); 
}
```

Comment: I am getting a The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process when trying this approach.

Comment: Sorry that the answer is so late, didn't notice it earlier. This should help: new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read). It allows multiple opening of the file as long as it is read access.

Comment: Couldn't get this to work.  If I remove the using's it gives out of memory exception. If it include the Using my mvc app is 302 re-directing to our error page...Not sure why.