# Response.TransmitFile always return back an empty file

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I Have created a method to download file from server. It 's seem that I can save the file to client, but the saved file is **always an empty file**( file size = 0KB ).

Did I miss something in my code?

My Front-end code:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
      Html.RenderAction("DownloadDocument", "Document", new { documentNode = Umbraco.TypedContent(CurrentPage.Id) });
}
```

And bellow is my DownloadDocument method in Document controller:

```
                var fileName = "myFile.docx"
                var filePath = @"D:\myFile.docx"
                Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename={fileName}");
                Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(filePath));
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
```

P/S:
    If I include **File Length** in the header, it throw a **Failed - Network error** from my client browser:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", new System.IO.FileInfo(fileName).Length.ToString());
```

Any help is appreciate!
Thanks!

Comment: Is filename={fileName} showing value? Can you check that? Post that value as well (if any).

Comment: @BijayKoirala: Yes, It have a value. I edited it. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Did you try it with the full path instead of just the filename in your header? e.g. Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename={filePath}");

Comment: Also, have a look at my answer fro a related question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43891035/5474410

Comment: Hi Hanus,
It is actually full path, and I also try your related answer, but it does not work( still empty file)