# Return Data and File from MVC Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC GET action that returns a json class model with a byte[] property, I use this to return a message and the file, but if the file is too big, I would get a OutOfMemoryException, is there any other way to return file and data that wouldn't use such memory?
I know I can create another action to return only the final file, but can I do it on the same request?
Edit:
**I don't want to use byte[] or any method that will load the file into memory**

```
 public ActionResult GetFile()
 {
    // Here: currently logic to create the final file and the message

    // Here: I want to add the final file to the result
    // Here: I want to add my model data(json) to the result

    // Here: currently returning json with a byte[] property to return the file
    return Json(myModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

Comment: (http://rion.io/2013/04/28/handling-larger-json-string-values-in-net-and-avoiding-exceptions/) or look into compressing your file into a .zip

Comment: It's already compressed

Comment: Maybe you need to increase the max json length property

Comment: the thing is, I don't want to use buffering, like using byte[] or string, and the only way to do this is using stream, but I don't know how to use it

Comment: So you don't want to use a byte array? Or you do? Because your post makes it sound like you want to use a byte array

Comment: Yep, I don't want to use byte[]

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826649/returning-a-file-to-view-download-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your restrictions you can do something tricky, if you are able to upload a file on the host, you can return the URL pf uploaded file in your JSON result and then let the user to download it.

In addition, you can find this link helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/51526234/7855321.

Comment: I think multipart could resolve it, but I can't find anything about returning it in MVC