# Difference between returning a Stream and writing to HTTP output stream

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, file, stream

What is the difference when returning files between

```
public Stream getFile(string filename){
    Stream s = _getFileStream(filename);
    Response.AddHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename+ ";" );
    return s;
}
```

and

```
public void getFile(string filename){
    byte[] b = _getFileBytes(filename);
    Response.AddHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename+ ";"  );
    Response.BinaryWrite(b)
}
```

and the method provided in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569336/some-questions-about-writing-on-asp-net-response-stream).

The problem I'm encountering is that sometimes parts of the image a user has uploaded appear scrambled. What's also odd is I cannot reproduce the problem locally - only when the application is on the www.

My thinking is that perhaps since my resources are local I wouldn't see the problem when streaming data and that the way I am streaming content back to the client isn't correct. So which is the "correct" (or recommended) way of returning the file?

Comment: First function does not write and data. 2nd returns undeclared variable `s` in a `void` function.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't proof-read. Both functions work for me. I just want to know if one is more better than the other and why.

Comment: If you're mixing WCF (I think, based on the tags in the question) with plain ASP.NET - you shouldn't do that. Either go full ASP.NET (and forget about `[ServiceContract]` and friends) where you can use the Response object, or go full WCF (where you return `Stream` but use the `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers` to add the returning header.

Comment: I am accessing the Response by <code>HttpContext.Current.Response</code>. I want to go the WCF route and avoid the ASP.net stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue with two changes.

1. I took what carlosfiguera said and changed  `HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeaders(...)` to `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Add(...)`
2. In my WebConfig I located the `binding` tag my service had it's `bindingCOnfiguration` set to and changed `transferMode` to "Streamed"

These two changes got my images showing up correctly.